# Is there a programming forum somewhere, where novices can ask stupid questions without being showered with downvotes?

Tags: discussion

I really like SO and I try to ask good questions but I'm not there yet. I have more questions that I want to ask but often I don't dare.

This is probably a bad question, too, so start clicking...

Comment: I am sure there are lots of them. Look around.

Comment: Forums don't *have* downvotes. Pick one, post your question. Just remember: Stack Overflow *is not a forum*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: depends on the forum.

Comment: @Wooble: the *majority of forums* then. I rarely use forums, I haven't come across any.

Comment: If you read [How to ask of SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and followed the advices there, unless it's a clear and easily findable duplicate, you shouldn't get downvoted.

Comment: We don't (at least shouldn't) be downvoting a question because we think it is stupid because someone is obviously having trouble with it. I answered one last night which I thought was a little silly because the documentation seems pretty clear as well as the answer (of mine) the OP linked to in the question. BUT, the OP had researched it and showed that with code, links, and exactly what issue he was having including the error. Point is, **try** and you should be fine no matter how "stupid" others think your question is.

Comment: @codeMagic: there are no stupid well-researched and clear questions. There are stupid questions, but they're not those ones.

Comment: @Wooble I completely agree which is the reason for the quotes. The question I was referring to I thought was silly because it was pretty direct but I didn't call it stupid and I answered it in more detail because it did show effort. That was my point is that as long as it shows a good effort and the information needed then they shouldn't be afraid to post it (I hope that isn't the vibe the community gives off)

Comment: *"This is probably a bad question, too"*, so, **you know** how to recognize a bad question...

Comment: Sorry. I was frustrated in the moment and asked this question rashly. Your points are taken.

Comment: Tough crowd, huh?

Answer (score 9):

*Should* there be a place where you can ask "stupid" questions without being showered with downvotes? We reward good questions with upvotes, and the asker with a little bit of reputation. Shouldn't poorly-researched or unanswerable questions cost you a little bit of reputation?

If you go to any programming forum on the Internet and ask bad questions you're likely to get flamed for it. Stack Overflow diverts some of the worst flaming into downvotes. I think it's a fair trade.

If one of your questions is downvoted and closed, don't take it personally. Just follow the guidelines in the close message to improve your question. If *many* of your questions are downvoted and closed, please take the time to read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines on asking good questions.

Comment: s/stupid/bad/  ?

Comment: @keyser I was echoing the title, so I added quotes around it.

Answer (score 8):

Don't make it harder than it has to be.

1. Have an actual question.
2. Do your research - use Google and SO to see if it's been asked before.
3. Show your attempt to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above, *should* there be a place for stupid questions? I don't think so. Too many people come here to ask questions that are already solved due to their laziness to search for and find their answers.  As a community, Stack Overflow does a good job in rewarding people when questions are asked in a way that spells out detail and a fully researched/designed question.

Like Bill the Lizard said, if your question gets downvoted, brush it off and don't take it personally. Take what you learned from that downvoted question and improve on it for the next that you ask.

Comment: Actually, you're right about laziness. I didn't properly research my downvoted questions and I probably could have answered them myself.